# unhandled exception at msvcr100d.dll

Tags: c++, c

I got a unhandled exception error at runtime when using the following C++ code, you can follow the error with debug using Visual Studio. Why will this exception happen, can you explain it?

First I define a class with a menber variable "_name"

```
void insert_Fenster(int pos,wstring name);
wstring get_Fenster_name(int pos);

class Fenster
{
public:
    Fenster(wstring name)
        :_name(name)
    {}

    void reload()
    {
        _name;
        insert_Fenster(1,L"temp");
        wstring tmp = get_Fenster_name(1);
        _name = tmp; //ERROR!!!
    }

    wstring get_name()
    {
        return _name;
    }

private:
    wstring _name;
};
```

Second I define a class to hold a map of the class

```
class FensterManager
{
public:
    bool has(int pos)
    {
        if (_mapFenster.find(pos)!=_mapFenster.end())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    void insert(int pos,wstring name)
    {
        if (has(pos))
        {
            _mapFenster.erase(pos);
        }
        _mapFenster.insert(make_pair(pos,Fenster(name)));
    }

    Fenster& get_Fenster(int pos)
    {
        return _mapFenster.at(pos);
    }

private:
    static map<int,Fenster> _mapFenster;
};
```

And some util functions

```
void insert_Fenster(int pos,wstring name)
{
    FensterManager fm;
    fm.insert(pos,name);
}

void reload_Fenster(int pos)
{
    FensterManager fm;
    if (fm.has(pos))
        fm.get_Fenster(pos).reload();
}

wstring get_Fenster_name(int pos)
{
    wstring name;

    FensterManager fm;
    if (fm.has(pos))
        name = fm.get_Fenster(pos).get_name();

    return name;
}

//Init of static member before main function
map<int,Fenster> FensterManager::_mapFenster;
```

that is the main function

```
void main()
{
    insert_Fenster(1,L"xyz");
    reload_Fenster(1);
}
```

The exception happen at "reload" function in class "Fenster".

With error message:
Unhandled exception at 0x005cca34 (msvcr100d.dll) in Regular_Expression.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xfeeefeee.

Comment: Please post original code message

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x005cca34 (msvcr100d.dll) in Regular_Expression.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xfeeefeee.

Comment: BTW Why does the code have the comment `//ERROR!!!` Is that wishful thinking or another error? Or the same error? Or a pointless comment?

Comment: that is only a mark where the error happens

Comment: `0xFEEEFEEE` is heap data that was freed/deleted.

Comment: Backtrace from debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `reload_Fenster(1);`, it will call `Fenster::reload`. In that function you call `insert_Fenster(1,L"temp");`. `FensterManager::insert` will first erase position 1 from the map. So when you return to `Fenster::reload`, the instance has been deleted. As soon as you try to access `_name`, you try to access memory which has been deleted.

**edit:**
To clarify; this function call:

```
fm.get_Fenster(pos).reload();
```

will first call `fm.get_Fenster(pos)` and then call `reload()` on the result. If `fm.get_Fenster(pos)` changes in the `reload()` function, execution will not move the new Fenster, but the old one will keep executing. Even if you delete the old Fenster.

You should make sure not to delete an instance if you are still running functions inside it. It will crash the application as soon as you try to access members, because they are stored in memory which has been deleted.

Comment: This answer seems spot on.

Comment: but after erase it also insert position 1 to the map `_mapFenster.insert(make_pair(pos,Fenster(name)));`

Comment: @rich yes, but you create a new Fenster there. `Fenster::reload` is still executing the old instance. `*this` will not change in the `Fenster::reload` function.

Comment: There you make a 'new' `Fenster`. Thus overwriting the current `Fenster` in position `pos` (1). That means you call `Fenster.0.reload` insert `Fenster.1` to location 0 overwriting `Fenster.0`. That means _after_ the `insert` function `Fenster.0` is no longer valid and has been deleted from memory.

Comment: @Wimmel  you are right, this will not change because the new instance is only a value. I have found a way to swap the old with a new one like this: `std::swap(_mapFenster[pos],Fenster(name));` stead of erase and it work! Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

looks like something inside `void insert_Fenster(int pos,wstring name);` - look further up the call stack and you'll see which part of your code is calling into the runtime dll. That'll be the error.

Comment: why would be `insert_Fenster`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide more information regarding the unhandled exception.

There is one obvious mistake in the above code. The insert_Fenster is inserting into a FensterManager instance and the reload_Fenster is trying to reload from a different instance of the FensterManager which is wrong.

```
void main()
{
    FensterManager fm;
    insert_Fenster(fm, 1,L"xyz");
    reload_Fenster(fm, 1);
}
```

The insert and reload method should be updated as follows:

```
void insert_Fenster(FensterManager &fm, int pos,wstring name)
{
    fm.insert(pos,name);
}

void reload_Fenster(FensterManager &fm, int pos)
{
    if (fm.has(pos))
        fm.get_Fenster(pos).reload();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but, for some crazy reason the data is static: `static map<int,Fenster> _mapFenster;` Of course, your way is better, but I don't believe that's the problem. I also don't believe the code as posted compiles.

Comment: yes, that is different instance, but both hold the same static member

Comment: @rich You do realise that is a very confusing thing to do and might want to consider a redesign

Comment: @rich It is probably less confusing if you make all functions in the FensterManager class static too, so you don't need a FensterManager instance any more.

Comment: @doctorlove sometimes so a design is useful for some big software